# How to create application with multiple tabs

Tags: macos, cocoa

I can't find any examples how to create application that manages tabs, like Finder or Safary.

What widget need to use for this purposes?

Comment: You'd have to make this yourself. At least there isn't a 'widget' i'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public API that allows you to use tabs like Finder or Safari. However there are third party APIs that allows you to create a similar tab effect such as [MMTabBarControl](https://github.com/mimo42/MMTabBarView/), or [Chromium Tabs](https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs) which allows you to create tabs like chrome.