# Which library for multiple tabs in Mac OS to use

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, tabs

How I can use some sort of tab view in my Mac OS application like in tabs in finder?

If there is no access to finder tab view then which library I can use to replace this functionality?

I found with [How to create application with multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576080/how-to-create-application-with-multiple-tabs) question, but it is one year old and only has two answers.

For now I found few outdated libraries on github, may be somebody can help with good maintained examples?

Comment: [cocoa controls](http://cocoacontrols.com) has a large selection of controls. There are many tab views to be found there.

Answer (score 0):

I used MMTabBarView library and made simple example project https://github.com/AlexMarlo/MMTabBarView-example